# A search form for multiple db fields

Tags: php, mysql

Actually, I'm trying to to create a search form for a personal website that have single search form and multiple DB fields. if data match with input value then that field or similar all fields will echo .
examples:

guess i have 5 fields in my db:

```
$f1, $f2, $f3, $f5
```

and all of them containing some string like

```
$f1 = "Hello there I'm f1, look at the outside";
$f2 = "Hello there I'm f2, be brave on you";
$f3 = "Hello there I'm f3,Do great things";
$f4 = "Hello there I'm f4, drink somethings";
$f5 = "Hello there I'm f5, eat somethings";
```

Now guess `$search` is a input field there we will search all data stored on those variable.
If we type `look at the outside` this string only on our input html field then `$f1` will echo the whole data of `$f1` but if we search with `Hello there I'm` this strings then it will `echo` our all of variables because in all of them this strings available. I think that examples will help you to understand properly what my requirement actually.

problems facing on working:

searching data if match any data then all fields are showing as i used echo keyword of php on foreach loop for all fields.

Snippets here:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_GET['submit_value']) && !empty($_GET['search_input']))
 {
    include("db_config.php");    
    $db = database::getInstance();
    $searchValue = $_GET['search_input'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `sitedata` WHERE c_main_title LIKE '%$searchValue%' OR c_main_body LIKE '%$searchValue%' OR cmt_dept_title LIKE '%$searchValue%' OR cmt_dept_body LIKE '%$searchValue%' OR aidt_dept_title LIKE '%$searchValue%' OR aidt_dept_body LIKE '%$searchValue%' OR food_dept_title LIKE '%$searchValue%' OR food_dept_body LIKE '%$searchValue%' OR rac_dept_title LIKE '%$searchValue%' OR rac_dept_body LIKE '%$searchValue%' OR p_message_title LIKE '%$searchValue%' OR p_message_body LIKE '%$searchValue%' OR vp_message_title LIKE '%$searchValue%' OR vp_message_body LIKE '%$searchValue%' OR about_college_title LIKE '%$searchValue%' OR about_college_body LIKE '%$searchValue%' OR mission_message LIKE '%$searchValue%' OR vision_message LIKE '%$searchValue%' ";    
// Now i want to match fields with my $searchValue var  if fields match with input data then that fields will echo. otherwise won't.

    $result = $db->dbc->query($sql);
    foreach( $result as $row)
    {
        // Now i need to use condition here to show my data which match with input field.
        // like $field1 = " hello world this is me" and user input value = "hello world"; then this will show up!
        echo "<h2 class='all-header'>".$row['c_main_title']."</h2>";
        echo $row['c_main_body'];
        echo "<h2 class='all-header'>".$row['cmt_dept_title']."</h2>";
        echo $row['cmt_dept_body'];
        echo "<h2 class='all-header'>".$row['aidt_dept_title']."</h2>";
        echo $row['aidt_dept_body'];
        echo "<h2 class='all-header'>".$row['food_dept_title']."</h2>";
        echo $row['food_dept_body'];
        echo "<h2 class='all-header'>".$row['p_message_title']."</h2>";
        echo $row['p_message_body'];
        echo "<h2 class='all-header'>".$row['vp_message_title']."</h2>";
        echo $row['vp_message_body'];
        echo "<h2 class='all-header'>".$row['about_college_title']."</h2>";
    }                                        
 }
 else { echo "<h2 class='not-found'>404 not found !</h2>";}
?>
```

Comment: What happen with your above code?

Comment: You can't find out from that DB query which field matched the search term. You have to set up separate search queries for that.

Comment: problems facing on working:

searching data if match any data then all fields are showing as i used echo keyword of php on foreach loop for all fields.

Comment: But i want this to act different !

Comment: Can you edit your question and clarify in detail what exactly is required?

Comment: More description ? I don't know how to i can add more description and i think description enough and requirement enough already added. Then too i will try to add somethings more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this before displaying each field or whatever you need to display (below code for first field)

```
if(strpos($row['c_main_title'], $searchValue) !== false || strpos($row['c_main_body'], $searchValue) !== false){
    echo "<h2 class='all-header'>".$row['c_main_title']."</h2>";
    echo $row['c_main_body'];
}
```

Comment: In this case `$row['c_main_title']` will only check values with user input form. but i need to use both like `$row['c_main_title']` and `$row['c_main_body]`  to compare with entered user strings. hope you understood

Comment: and check also i added enough description for more understand !

Comment: Clear to me somethings more: when i will use others on another condition then where i will use them ? I'm trying but it's not searching data properly. where i need to use the next condition ? as a child if or outside the if ? or elseif ? [Check this](https://gist.github.com/MahbbRah/45c25c76eb4f6b7f3a45de69b1d72f4a)

Comment: For the next field you need to use a similar if structure independent of the first i.e. after the first if ends.

Comment: Please check this code and say somethings? https://gist.github.com/MahbbRah/45c25c76eb4f6b7f3a45de69b1d72f4a

Comment: Use only if statement and not elseif. If you use elseif only one statement which first runs true will be executed and not anymore.

Comment: Thank you dear for your help ! It's worked but after that, I get a better algorithm to do this things with less code !